# How to create a list from a for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to create a list of numbers from a function and a for-loop. Here is a copy of my code:

```
Rh = 1096776000000

print "What is your value for 'n'?"
n = float(raw_input(">"))

m = range(int(n+1), int(n+21))

def wavelength(a,b):
    list = [((1 / (Rh * ((1 / (a**2)) - (1 / (float(x)**2))))) * 10 ** 14)
    for x in b]
    return list


for elements in wavelength(n,m):
    print "%.3f" % elements, 'nm'
```

This will print out what I want, but I need to take all of the data points and put them into a list. Any ideas?

Comment: But the data is already in a list. What's wrong with `result = wavelength(n,m)`?

Comment: Not the right rounding, I'm guessing, @kevin

Comment: I agree with @Kevin. Data is already there, there's no need to copy and manage a second list just because of rounding. Stored data should be as precise as possible and should be appropriately formatted only when it's accessed.

Comment: I get that, but I'm guessing his rounding wasn't for no reason either. "Only when it's accessed"... What if he wants to access it now? Anyhow, I answered the question in the format OP (seems to have) intended.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're in need of something like this:

```
l = [] # An empty list
for elements in wavelength(n,m):
    l.append("%.3f" % elements, 'nm') # Adding rounded values to the list
print l # Print the full list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results = ["%.3f nm" % elements for elements in wavelength(n,m)]
```